# How to add the maven generated findbugs,pmd,checkstyle reports in sonarqube 7.4

Tags: maven, sonarqube, checkstyle, findbugs

I generated the reports by passing the maven command:

```
mvn clean package findbugs:findbugs checkstyle:checkstyle sonar:sonar
```

And those generated reports were put into target folder.
And in Sonarqube 7.4 which has an option to import xml reports under External Analyzers I gave the path to those reports. But I get only the reports of default rules of SonarWay Quality profile.I'm not able to see the checkstyle and findbugs reports anywhere.

Is the method what i'm doing is wrong or some problem in maven or sonar.. If so how can i find the root cause?

```
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports/</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
<sonar.java.checkstyle.reportPaths>./target/site/checkstyle-result.xml</sonar.java.checkstyle.reportPaths>
<sonar.java.findbugs.reportPaths>./target/site/findbugsXml.xml</sonar.java.findbugs.reportPaths>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<sonar.java.binaries>target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>
<project.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.sourceEncoding>
<sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
<sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
<sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.inclusions>src\main\webapp\scripts\custom\DataCenterInventory.js,src\main\java\com\igate\drawit\controller\dataCenterController.java,src\main\java\com\igate\drawit\daoimpl\datacenterDgmDAOImpl.java,src\main\java\com\igate\drawit\dao\datacenterDgmDAO.java,src\main\webapp\scripts\custom\viewDatacenter.js</sonar.inclusions>

<reporting>
  <outputDirectory>target\site</outputDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <!-- Optional directory to put findbugs xdoc xml report -->
        <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <!-- Optional directory to put findbugs xdoc xml report -->
        <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```